# How to run laravel queue without `queue:listen` command?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using a `laravel queue` to send the push notification with 10 second delay. I have set up a queue and its working fine locally when I run following command.

```
php artisan queue:listen database
```

Without this command the queue will not work(Correct me if I am wrong). But suppose if I deployed a project on server, then I want run `laravel queue` without using above command.

**Is there any another option to run queue?**

Comment: You have to use it. What you do is run the command and keep it alive as part of your deploy process